# Glow effect for lines drawn in InkCanvas

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, inkcanvas

I'm using the WPF InkCanvas for a drawing application. The canvas is over a image. I can scribble over the image OK but I need it to have a glow effect - i.e. the actual lines drawn must have this effect. Is there a way to do this in XAML or in the C# code?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a ShaderEffect and attach it to the [UIElement.Effect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.effect(v=vs.110).aspx) of the InkCanvas. [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect(v=vs.110).aspx) MSDN article contains a sample that shows how to write ShaderEffects.

Try starting with the excellent set of ShaderEffects implemented in the [Windows Presentation Foundation Pixel Shader Effects Library](https://wpffx.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks, I will look into implementing a ShaderEffect. BTW, is there a canned ShaderEffect that will do this? If not I can look into implementing one.

Comment: The library I linked to has some canned effects you can use to get started.

Comment: Thanks, I think it will be a good starting point, I'll look into trying it.